# Not able to connect tridion 2013 with java using core service, getting The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized

Tags: core-service

I am not able to connect to cms with java using core service.

I have done the following steps

> core-service url i am using like
>   http://CMS-Server/webservices/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl

maven configuration is like

```
<build>
    <finalName>generated-webservices</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated/src/main/java</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlUrls>
                    <wsdlUrl>http://CMS-Server/webservices/CoreService2011.svc?wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                </wsdlUrls>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/target/generated/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Use current JAX-WS RI version -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.7</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <xmlConfigs>
                    <xmlConfig implementation="java.io.File">${basedir}/src/main/resources/config/xmlbeans.xsdconfig</xmlConfig>
                </xmlConfigs>
                <sourceGenerationDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</sourceGenerationDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

- created authenticator class

  ```
  public class BasicHttpAuthenticator extends Authenticator {

  private final String user;
  private final String password;

  public BasicHttpAuthenticator(String user, String password) {
      this.user = user;
      this.password = password;
  }

  @Override
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
      return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password.toCharArray());
  }
  }
  ```

connecting to core service like

```
private static final QName Q_NAME = new QName("http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService","CoreService2011");

public String connectCoreService() throws Exception {
    BasicHttpAuthenticator basicHttpAuthenticator = new BasicHttpAuthenticator(username, password);
    Authenticator.setDefault(basicHttpAuthenticator);
    URL url = new URL(wsdl);
    CoreService2011 service = new CoreService2011(url,Q_NAME);
    ICoreService endpoint = service.getBasicHttp();
    UserData currentUser = endpoint.getCurrentUser();
    System.out.println(String.format("'%s' %s", currentUser.getTitle(), currentUser.getId()));
    return "core service connected";
}
```

but getting error at time when calling

```
endpoint.getCurrentUser();
```

with error message :-

> Oct 14, 2016 2:13:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher-servlet] in
>   context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed;
>   nested exception is com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException:
>   The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized] with root cause
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP
>   status code 401: Unauthorized     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.checkStatusCode(HttpTransportPipe.java:203)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.process(HttpTransportPipe.java:179)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.processRequest(HttpTransportPipe.java:94)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.DeferredTransportPipe.processRequest(DeferredTransportPipe.java:116)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:598)    at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:557)  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:542)   at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:439)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.Stub.process(Stub.java:222)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.doProcess(SEIStub.java:135)     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:109)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:89)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:118)   at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy66.getCurrentUser(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.test.cms.coreservice.controllers.CoreServiceController.connectCoreService(CoreServiceController.java:53)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

please provide some input, so that would help me to solve this.

Comment: Are you running the Java client directly on the server - if so, does the Core Service webservice accept "Basic Authentication"

Comment: Hi Dylan, 
I am running client from my machine and trying to connect CMS server and failing, but i can connect cms directly from browser and authentication of my machine is different from authentication of cms.

Comment: Neetesh - can you update your question to clarify _that is doesn't work under s specific condition but it does in others_ so readers can better visual the scenario you're in. And on that - I believe that if you run it from the application it will be trying to connect via Basic Authentication and not using the credentials you supply in code - thus you should confirm that (1) Basic Authentication is permitted through the webservice and (2) the user you are logged in has the permissions required to access the webservice.

Comment: Hi Dylan, i am providing correct authentication through which i connect cms, but i suspect that when using Basic Authentication it is picking my machine authentication, although i am not able to find actual problem, to run application from cms server i don't have permission right now, if i get permission then i check and update the question.

Answer (score 2):

If this works when using your browser but doesn't when you try to use the application directly / on the server then it could be that the application will be trying to connect via *Basic Authentication* and **not** using the credentials you supply in code.

You should confirm that

- Basic Authentication is permitted through the webservice and
- the **user** you are **logged in** has the permissions required to access the webservice

Comment: Dylan, Thanks for your feedback, I've tried with Binding username and password property to client and i can access CMS now.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried by binding username and password property, which i was missing.

so i have removed  this line

> ICoreService endpoint = service.getBasicHttp();

and added

```
    ICoreService client = service.getPort(ICoreService.class);
    BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) client;
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "domain\\username");
    bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");
```

after this now i am able to access cms using core service

```
public String connectCoreService() throws Exception {

        BasicHttpAuthenticator basicHttpAuthenticator = new BasicHttpAuthenticator(username, password);
        Authenticator.setDefault(basicHttpAuthenticator);

        URL url = new URL(wsdl);
        CoreService2011 service = new CoreService2011(url, Q_NAME);

        ICoreService client = service.getPort(ICoreService.class);
        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) client;
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "domain\\username");
        bp.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");

        UserData currentUser = client.getCurrentUser();
        System.out.println(String.format("'%s' %s", currentUser.getTitle().getValue(), currentUser.getId().getValue()));
        return "core service connected";
    }
```